# Use Flutter 'file', what is the correct path to read txt file in the lib directory?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using the flutter 'file', trying to read a `txt` file in lib directory, but I do not know how should I write in code to read the file. I also do not know if I have placed the `txt` file at a right place, which means I do not know if I can read the file in the lib directory.

I have put a `txt` file `words.txt` in the lib directory, where other dart files are put.

Below is my code which tries to read the 'word.txt' file:

```
Future<String> readFile() async {
  var text;
  try {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);

    final file = File('${directory.path}/lib/words.txt');
    text = await file.readAsString();
    return text;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

P.S. I have imported the 'dart:io' and 'path_provider.dart'.

When I run the program, I can see the directory.path is printed in the console, however the e.message 'Cannot open file' is printed in the console.

I think that the error is came from 'File('${directory.path}/lib/words.txt')', so i would like to know how should i write code to read the txt file in lib directory.

Thanks.

Comment: better put it in assets. read the answer below for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an assets folder in your project's root folder. In Android Studio you can right click the Project outline and go to `New > Directory`.

So now you should have

```
root folder
  --android
  --ios
  --lib
  --assets
  --build
```

**Add your text file to the new folder**

You can just copy your text file into the assets directory. The relative path of `words.txt`, for example, would be `assets/words.txt`.

Open the pubspec.yaml file that is in the root of your project.
Update it as

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/words.txt
```

---

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  var s =  await rootBundle.loadString('assets/my_text.txt');
  print(s);//for debug
  return s;
}
```